# VLC indicator shows it is not active while playing audio

Tags: 16.04, suspend, pulseaudio, indicator, vlc

The VLC indicator has been showing that the application is not active while I am playing audio.

[image]

As shown above, the indicator shows an inactive VLC but we can clearly see that VLC is active and playing some audio files. What could be the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What audio server are you using to play your audio - ALSA (Advanced Linux Sound Architecture) or Pulseaudio or OSS? By default Ubuntu comes with Pulseaudio, which runs over ALSA, and you should be using Pulseaudio if you have not made any changes. In case you have ALSA as your default or preferred audio server on your active sound card, then as a matter of fact ALSA supports and allows audio only over 1 particular stream at a time. I myself had a lot of trouble playing mp3 files on VLC and html5 videos on the internet simultaneously.

Try closing all other media players and only use VLC to play.

In the system monitor, check whether you are having the Pulseaudio daemon running. If not, then I think you are using  ALSA as the default audio server and you won't be able to play audio over 2 streams simultaneously.

If you are using Pulseaudio, you should be able to play audio on VLC along with the other program as well, and it should indicate that VLC is actively playing audio.

Comment: ythI am using pulse audio. i can play two sound from both VLC and Rythmbox at the same time. The only problem is that the indicator itself shows inactive for VLC. The indicator for Rythmbox works just fine.

Comment: Why do you want to play audio from 2 different media players at the same time? When you play sound from only VLC and no other media player is active, does the indicator show active for VLC?